# \textbf command not working when using polyglossia

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, hindi

I am trying to write in multiple Indian languages in the same document using `polyglossia` package, but when I use it the `\textbf` command does not work and the pieces of text which were written in bold in the document get changed to normal. Also the font seems to change a bit. Following is the code snippet I used for writing in Hindi:

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hindi}

\newfontfamily\devanagarifont{Lohit Devanagari}[Script=Devanagari]

\begin{document}

\texthindi{नमस्ते}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please always provide a test file not just a fragment, so people can reproduce  and test answers. Does that font have a bold version?

Comment: The log will give a warning: `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'TU/{Lohit Devanagari}(0)/b/n' undefined` if there is no bold version. I can find only regular Lohit fonts; no bold, italic, bolditalic, etc.

Comment: I got the answer to this question, basically I was using a package 'times' which was causing some incompatibility, so I removed it and it solved the problem.